# Add signingConfigs on gradle-experimental:0.1.0

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Following Experimental Plugin User Guide 
[Android Tools Project Site](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental) of **gradle-experimental:0.1.0**, my question is, who create **signingConfigs** and add them to differents *buildTypes* How enable **multidex**?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32187457/2016562

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the multiDex support you have to add that to the android blob, as for signingConfigs that goes right outside of the android blob.

```
model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 22
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.0 rc3"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "com.my.project"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 14
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 22

            // Enabling multidex support
            multiDexEnabled = true
        }
    }

    // signingConfig blob
    android.signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file(project.property("Project.signing") + ".keystore")
            storePassword "storePass"
            keyAlias "keyAlias"
            keyPassword "keyPass"
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. it gives me an error: `The following model rules are unbound:
    model.android.signingConfigs > named(release)`