# Signing android apk with gradle-experimental:0.2.0

Tags: android, gradle, java-native-interface, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have successfully modified my build.gradle to work with gradle-experimental however when trying to add a signingConfigs block it fails.  I followed the instructions from http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental as best I can but i always get the following error:

> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>
> > The following model rules are unbound:
> >         model.android.signingConfigs > named(release)
> >           Mutable:
> >             - android.signingConfigs.release (com.android.build.gradle.managed.SigningConfig)

I search for the error but couldn't find anything relevant.  What does "The following model rules are unbound" mean?

Here's what my signingConfig block looks like, it's outside the android block and modified to use = as is the case when using gradle-experimental.

```
android.signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile = file("myreleasekey.keystore")
        storePassword = "password"
        keyAlias = "MyReleaseKey"
        keyPassword = "password"
    }
}
```

Comment: For the time being, I ended up working around this issue by scripting the manual signing steps, which is likely a reason that this issue may not currently have a gradle centric solution.

Comment: Try following:
In the second line replace 
<release {>   
by   
<create("release") {>

Comment: @mdew thanks, I tried it and the create statement works.  Now when I try to reference it from within buildTypes.release with `signingConfig = signingConfigs.release` I get "Error:Attempt to read a write only view of model of type 'java.lang.Object' given to rule 'model.android.buildTypes'", any clue what's going wrong?

Comment: @gtkp Did you find any solution for it? I tried with experimental gradle 0.4.0, and facing the same problem. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding release keys in the experimental Gradle plugin for Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32109501/adding-release-keys-in-the-experimental-gradle-plugin-for-android). I posted [a solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34461486/45668) there.

Answer (score 3):

Although, it's late for the user who asked this question, still it may help others.

Following code sample is working fine for me. I tested it with following settings - Gradle-experimental-0.4.0, Gradle wrapper - 2.8, Android Studio 2.0 Preview edition.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    def signConf // <-- Note the changes made here

    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.0"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "in.atultiwari.helloandroidjni"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 15
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
            versionCode = 1
            versionName = "1.0"
        }
    }
    android.buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles.add(file("proguard-rules.pro"))
            signingConfig = signConf // <-- Note the changes made here
        }
    }
    android.signingConfigs { // <-- Note the changes made here
        create("signRelease") { // <-- Note the changes made here
            keyAlias = 'myKeyAlias'
            keyPassword = 'myKeyPassword'
            storeFile = file('myKestoreFile.jks')
            storePassword = 'myKeystorePassword'
            signConf = it
        }
    }
    android.ndk {
        moduleName = "hello-android-jni"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

P.S. - it's **not** working with `minifyEnabled = true`, in which case a error related to `transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease` occurs.

**Edit - 1.** `minifyEnabled = true` is working with above settings. Turns out I had my proguard-rules file was empty, and somehow it was causing the mentioned error.

Comment: I get an error: `No such property signingConfigs for class com.android.build.gradle.managed.BuildType`

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to add signing for gradle experimental 0.7:
apply plugin: "com.android.model.application"

```
model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
        buildTypes {
            release {
                signingConfig = $("android.signingConfigs.myConfig")
            }
        }
    }
    android.signingConfigs {
        create("myConfig") {
            storeFile "/path/to/debug.keystore"
            storePassword "android"
            keyAlias "androiddebugkey"
            keyPassword "android"
            storeType "jks"
        }
    }
}
```

Find out more info about gradle experimental:0.7.0 here:
[Experimental Plugin User Guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental)